# Laravel Eloquent: How to show a few articles from each categories

Tags: php, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 Eloquent and feel confused how to solve this case;

I need to show/get a few articles from each categories. When I used this

```
   $cat = App\Category::with(
            array('articles' => function($query) {
              $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC'); 
          }))->get();
```

I got all of articles from categories. But, how to get when I only need five articles from each categories?

Comment: You mean you want to use limit? Categories or article?

Comment: Read this http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Comment: you can specify easily that you only want 5 articles per category in your view

Answer (score 0):

You can use `take()` for that:

```
 $cat = App\Category::with(
        array('articles' => function($query) {
          $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC'); 
          $query->take(5);
      }))->get();
```

Comment: It just get five articles of all categories. Not each.